# vscvarsall.bat not found when compiling f2py code

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I was trying to compile some f2py code using the following python script (called build_f2py_modules.py)  as told to do by my professor, I am using python 3.6 and windows 10 64-bit:

```
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension
ext = Extension(name='Test',
    sources=['Sigma.f95'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(name='f2py_example',
        ext_modules =[ext])
```

and I run it in command prompt with the following command:

```
python build_f2py_modules.py build_ext
```

and I get the following error:

```
running build_ext
running build_src
build_src
building extension "Test" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.6\build\src.win-amd64-3.6\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.6\build\src.win-amd64-3.6' to include_dirs.
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'Test' extension
compiling C sources
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Do I have to download something? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if it wants Microsoft Visual C++ and that gcc won't do. You can probably download VS2017 Community Edition, making sure to do a non-default install and selecting the C++ component. https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-fortran-compilers-for-windows-integration-into-microsoft-visual-studio-2017 discusses this in the context of Intel compilers, but the VS configuration info is relevant too.